# Flask/Python application failed to start before deployment on Heroku

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku, flask

I would like to deploy a Flask (python) app on Heroku, I did it before without any problem . 
But now, I don't know what is the problem .

The problem is here, When I enter the following command to test the local server :

```
foreman start
```

I have this error :

```
foreman start
12:01:53 web.1  | started with pid 6055
12:01:53 web.1  | 2013-12-25 12:01:53 [6058] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
12:01:53 web.1  | 2013-12-25 12:01:53 [6058] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (6058)
12:01:53 web.1  | 2013-12-25 12:01:53 [6058] [INFO] Using worker: sync
12:01:53 web.1  | 2013-12-25 12:01:53 [6063] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6063
12:01:53 web.1  | 2013-12-25 12:01:53 [6063] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
12:01:53 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
12:01:53 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
12:01:53 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
12:01:53 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
12:01:53 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
12:01:53 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
12:01:53 web.1  |     __import__(module)
12:01:53 web.1  | ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
12:01:53 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
12:01:53 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
12:01:53 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
12:01:53 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
12:01:53 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
12:01:53 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
12:01:53 web.1  |   File "/home/myhome/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
12:01:53 web.1  |     __import__(module)
12:01:53 web.1  | ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
12:01:53 web.1  | 2013-12-25 12:01:53 [6063] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6063)
12:01:53 web.1  | 2013-12-25 12:01:53 [6058] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
12:01:53 web.1  | 2013-12-25 12:01:53 [6058] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
12:01:53 web.1  | exited with code 3
12:01:53 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

My Procfile is :

```
web: gunicorn app/route:app
```

And I am using this main :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
    handler = RotatingFileHandler('foo.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    if TODAY != cache.config['CACHE_ARGS'] :
        with app.app_context():
            cache.clear()
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 33507))
    app.run(debug = True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

When I run the app on the browser (0.0.0.0:33507) it works perfectly .

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this:

```
web: gunicorn app/route:app
```

be:

```
web: gunicorn app.route:app
```

Gunicorn github page says:

> Basic usage:
>
> $ gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE
>
> Where APP_MODULE is of the pattern $(MODULE_NAME):$(VARIABLE_NAME).
>   The module name can be a full dotted path. The variable name refers to
>   a WSGI callable that should be found in the specified module.

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn#gunicorn

Comment: No I don't think, because the route.py is in ./app/route.py why should I add the `.`. Anyway changing it gave me the same error :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well I found something helpful here : http://ryaneshea.com/lightweight-python-apps-with-flask-twitter-bootstrap-and-heroku

The `Procfile` should look like this :

```
web: python app/route.py
```

Comment: I don't see where on that page they say you need to use a slash. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @rednaw Thanks a lot for your answer, but if use your method : `web: gunicorn app.route:app` I will have this error `ImportError: No module named app.route`.

Comment: Well, that's a step closer to the solution. Previously you had the error "Import by filename is not supported" because you used a filename instead of a python module name. Now you have "No module named app.route", that means Python can't find the module. Are you sure you are pointing to the right module? Are you sure it's in your pythonpath?

Comment: I added route.py yo PYTHONPATH by doing :`PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/myHome/myApp/app/route.py ; export PYTHONPATH`. Yes I am pointing to the right module which is `route.py` (my WSGI). Check my ls output on @Michael answer, may be it can help .

Comment: a path in the `$PYTHONPATH` variable should be a directory, not a file. I think you should put it to `/home/myHome/myApp/` because relative to THAT directory, python can reach `app/route.py` through `app.route`.

Comment: `$ echo $PYTHONPATH` : `/home/myHome/myApp/app` and I still get the error :  `ImportError: No module named app.route`

Comment: First of all, I said `/home/myHome/myApp/`, not `/home/myHome/myApp/app/`. Besides that, you should append the directory to the pythonpath, like you did earlier: `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/myHome/myApp/ ; export PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your Procfile located? It should be in the main directory. Can you post your directory structure? Or do you have this project on Github?

Comment: `$ ls -a` : `.  ..  app  foo.log  .git  .gitignore  Procfile  .project  .pydevproject  requirements.txt  .settings  venv`
But it is ok since I found a solution and I posted it .

Comment: `$ ls -a` on app output's : `.  ..  foo.log  forms.py  forms.pyc  json  README.md  route.py  static  templates`

Answer (score 0):

Your Procfile should be

`web: gunicorn app.route:app`

And make sure that your folder `app` which contains `route.py` is a package which means the app folder should contain `__init__.py` to make app folder as package